# What is the meaning of White Bar on Chrome Frame Timeline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, animation

I recently built an application that uses smooth scrolling and parallax. But I found that my website is very jerky. I am able to push the process so that it uses lower resources and has frame rate below 60 FPS. But even then the white bar is shown on the Google timeline, thus the animation is becoming jerky and completely useless.

What is meaning of this white bar on chrome?

[image: long unknown white bar]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0_jD8nO5Zw) and looking at [the docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline), the white-ish bars is load that could not exactly be identified by the debug tools. Did you try ruling out external factors like chrome extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Light gray means uninstrumented time: The browser is working, but it's unclear what is happening.

Clear is idle time: Waiting for the next frame, etc.

See: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline#frames_mode

Comment: How come the white (waiting for next frame) bar pushes the frame over the 60fps line. If a frame has 10ms worth of work shouldn't the white bar just be the 6ms that is left over for 60fps?

Comment: I'm not sure where I picked this up, but I think if you're hitting the 60fps budget from time to time, the browser might decide to lower the frame rate to 30, even if you could go faster in some cases. This would be to provide a more homogenous animation. (If anyone can provide a source or prove me wrong, please go ahead)